# How set unique ID in dynamicRow?

Tags: magento2, dynamic-rows

I have field in dynamicRows:

```
<field name="on" component="Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/checkbox" sortOrder="0" formElement="checkbox">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                            <item name="inputCheckBoxName" xsi:type="string">default</item>
                            <item name="isMultiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="columnsHeaderClasses" xsi:type="string">control-table-options-th</item>
                            <item name="modules" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="rows" xsi:type="string">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = options</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <additionalClasses>
                            <class name="control-table-options-cell">true</class>
                        </additionalClasses>
                        <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                        <label translate="true">Is Enable?</label>
                    </settings>
                </field>
```

How I can set unique value?

ty for answer